# Keep steel cube afloat

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water, buoyancy, fluid-statics, volume

I have 1000 kg cube of steel. 
How much of air(volume) needed to keep it afloat(on water)?
[image]

I`ve been trying to find online calculator for this task, but with no success.

Comment: So the answer is **a million cc`s** of air  to keep the cube afloat, right?

Comment: I totally didn't understand what you mean. Can you draw an illustration?